# how to add different source images for different media breakpoint in gatsby-image?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I would like to add different source images for different media widths in my header using gatsby-images. The reason for doing so is that I need different crops of the same image for different viewports. In html we can just add multiple `<source>` tags inside the `<picture>` element, how can this be achieved with gatsby-image? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can add additional `<source>` to gatsby-image without doing something hacky, you're probably better off build your own component